# Run Tor as Client Only

Tags: proxy, tor, socks5

I'm running tor with the following command:

```
tor --ClientOnly 1 --RunAsDaemon 1 --CookieAuthentication 0 --ControlPort 8119 --PidFile tor1.pid --SocksPort 9051 --DataDirectory data/tor/tor1
```

This create an instance, which I can use via: 127.0.0.1:9051

However, when I create it, my bandwidth is fully used by tor. I am guessing as a relay. I've tried a lot of things, but nothing seems to change this. --ClientOnly 1 does nothing.

Does anyone know why this is using all my bandwidth and how to stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem was nothing to do with Tor being used as a relay. When you create a new tor instance it downloads about 8.5MB of data to the specified data directory. If you are creating multiple tor processes at once, this will cause a lot of bandwidth to be used. But once you have a data directory established, it does not download these files again. You can probably set multiple tor processes to run from the same data directory by specifying a different pid file for each process, using the command:

```
--PidFile tor$i.pid
```